# How to make a dynamic dropdownbutton list in Flutter ? (delete items)

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore, dropdownbutton

I have an issue with the dropdownbutton in Flutter. To make it quick, I have a list of cities in Cloud Firestore which is used to make the list (items) of the dropdownbutton. This list of cities is getted with a StreamBuilder so when I changed the name of a city, it is changed in real time. The problem here is if I select for exemple 'New York' and in Cloud Firestore I delete 'New York', the dropdownbutton can't find the value 'New York'. I wanted to know if there is a possible way for the dropdownbutton to rebuild and choose a valid value or an other way to manage the deletion of a value in the dropdownbutton ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a `setState()` method, so every time this method is called, your `DropDownButton` is redrawn.

> [Documentation : `Widget setState()`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/State/setState.html)

[image]

Here is the Solution you're looking for :

- I've demonstrated it with an `ElevatedButton()` which on click updates your list values with your "Firestore values"  and redraws the DropDownButton thanks to `setState()` method :

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class DropdownMenu extends StatefulWidget {
  const DropdownMenu({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<DropdownMenu> createState() => _DropdownMenuState();
}

/// This is the private State class that goes with MyStatefulWidget.
class _DropdownMenuState extends State<DropdownMenu> {
  var dropdownValue;

  String hintValue = 'Tout de Suite';
  List<String> values = [
    'Initial value 1',
    "Initial Value 2",
    'Initial value 3',
    "Initial Value 4",
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        ElevatedButton(
          onPressed: () {
            setState(() {
              values = [
                'New value from Firebase',
                "Values edited from firebase"
              ];
            });
          },
          child: Text("Update with current Firestore values "),
        ),
        DropdownButton<String>(
          value: dropdownValue,
          hint: Text(
            hintValue,
          ),
          underline: Container(
            height: 0,
          ),
          onChanged: (String? newValue) {
            setState(() {
              hintValue = newValue!;
            });
          },
          items: values.map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
            return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
              value: value,
              child: Text(
                value,
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black),
              ),
            );
          }).toList(),
        ),
      ],
    );
  }
}
```